# TypeError: in Solidity Contract ("should be marked as abstract")

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

**I get the following error message.**

```
TypeError: Contract "InterfaceB" should be marked as abstract.
```

**The error goes away once I change contract InterfaceB to interface InterfaceB.**

The code is as follows.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract InterfaceB {
    function getMessage() external pure returns(string memory);
}

contract ContractB {    
    function getMessage() pure external returns(string memory){
            return "Hellow World.";
    }
}
```

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to define an interface, you have to use `interface` keyword.

```
interface InterfaceB {
    function getMessage() external pure  returns(string memory);
}
```

Any contract that has at least one unimplemented function is treated as abstract in Solidity. In your case you have `contract InterfaceB` which has one unimplemented function:

```
  function getMessage() external pure returns(string memory);
```

so Remix detects that this is an abstract contract